# Call to a member function save() on null: PROBLEM IN UPDATING

Tags: arrays, laravel, datatables, record

I cannot update my record using foreach

**ScoreController.php**

```
public function updateScore(Request $request, $id)
{
     foreach ($request->score as $key => $id) {

        $scores =  Score::find($request->score[$key]); 
        $scores->save();
        }
    //dd($request->all());
    return redirect('/tabulation')->with('status', 'Score added!');
}
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach ($scores as $score)
<label for="{{$score->id}}" value="{{$score->id}}"></label>
<input type="text" name="score[]" value="{{$score->score}}"/>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `<label>` elements do not have a `value` attribute:

```
<label for="{{ $score->id }}" value="{{ $score->id }}"></label>
```

That `value="{{ $score->id }}"` does nothing, and isn't sent to the server. If you want to send the score's ID to the server, pass that in your input:

```
@foreach($scores AS $score)
<input type="text" name="scores[{{ $score->id }}]" value="{{ $score->score }}"/>
@endforeach
```

Next, in your controller, access your variables correctly:

```
foreach($request->input("scores") AS $id => $scoreValue){
  $score = Score::find($id);
  $score->score = $scoreValue;
  $score->save();
}
```

The reason you're getting `Call to a member function save() on null` is that you're trying to find a `Score` that has an id of whatever `$score->score` contains. You're not passing or referencing the `id` correctly.